# Call a graphics method in a child class

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, graphics, awt

I'm trying to call a graphics method in a child class from the main method. I'm having an issue with the graphics call. Here's what i'm doing:

```
        Graphics gr = null;
        frame.paint(childClass.repaint(gr));
```

When i execute the code i'm getting a NullPointerException, presumably because the graphics object is being set to null. However if i don't do that, the code won't execute because the graphics object isn't initialized.
For reference here is the code i'm calling in the child class:

```
public Graphics repaint(Graphics gr)
{

   super.paint(gr);

   setEyes();


   Color eyeColor = Color.BLACK;
   gr.setColor(getColour());
   gr.fillOval(50, 100, getHeadSize(), getHeadSize());       
   int count;
   int offset = 90;
   for(count = 0; count < getEyes(); count++)
   {
       gr.setColor(eyeColor);
       gr.fillOval(offset, 150, 15, 15);
       offset = offset+50;
   }

   gr.setColor(getColour());
   gr.drawLine(125, 250, 125, 250+getBodyHeight());
   gr.drawLine(75, 275, 75+getBodyWidth(), 275);
   gr.drawLine(75, 275, 60, 275+getArmLength());
   gr.drawLine(75+getBodyWidth(), 275, 90+getBodyWidth(), 275+getArmLength());
  return gr;
}
```

Note that the drawing code works as expected when written in the main method, but it must be in the child class.

Thanks for any help.

Edited to add...

I need to be able to call this from the child class. Is there anyway at all to call a graphics method that is located in a child class from the main method?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The problem is not contained within the repaint class that i posted. It's simply there for reference. If you read the first part of the post you'd see that the question is very precise

Comment: ..was that comment to me?  I can see nothing in it that remotely relates to posting an SSCCE.  *"you'd see that the question is very precise"*  What I see is a post that does not even contain a single '?'.  If you have a question, add one to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with painting, the best course of action is for you to override `paintComponent` and do all your drawing in there. Afterwards, anytime you need to update your scene, call `repaint` and only `repaint`. Here is a quick example of how you would use this approach:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Painter extends JComponent{

    private Art myArt = new Art();

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        myArt.draw(g2d);

    }


    private class Art{

        public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Painter is Java reserved words for synth Painter, can be misspeled

Comment: I get that, but class names were chosen to emphasise each role, not to go into production code :P